# Реализация удаления и изменения строк файла в Python

Tags: python, файлы

Как в Python реализовать:

1. Удаление отдельной строки с ключевыми словами (вводишь слово, которое там находится, и эта строка находится). Также удаление всех данных из файла.
2. Редактирование отдельных строк по ключевым словам (как выше).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще прочитать файл в список, модифицировать полученный список как надо и записать файл заново. Нижеследующий пример как раз демонстрирует такое. Файл разбивается на строки и считывается в список. Каждый элемент списка — строка, оканчивающаяся символом `\n`. Поэтому когда заменяется строка целиком, это надо учесть.

```
# открытие файла, чтение, закрытие
with open("имя_файла", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# удаление строк, для которых выполнено условие
data = filter(lambda line: "стоп_слово" not in line, data)

# более сложные условия редактирования стоит вынести в отдельную функцию
def transformation(line):
    if "слово_маркер" in line:
        return "замещающая строка\n"
    return line.replace("что_заменить", "на_что")

# редактирование строк файла
data = map(transformation, data)

# открытие, запись и закрытие файла
with open("имя_файла", "w") as f:
    f.write("".join(data))
```